# Cache issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I built my first web app using Ruby, and I noticed the server is super slow when trying to load each page. The following lines are reapeated at least 10 times:

```
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Entreprise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entreprises".* FROM "entreprises" WHERE "entreprises"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "b50b7beb-7417-4110-b602-660e9ecf067e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Entreprise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entreprises".* FROM "entreprises" WHERE "entreprises"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "b50b7beb-7417-4110-b602-660e9ecf067e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] [1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8] ConferencierChannel stopped streaming from conferencier_channel
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Entreprise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entreprises".* FROM "entreprises" WHERE "entreprises"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "b50b7beb-7417-4110-b602-660e9ecf067e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Entreprise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entreprises".* FROM "entreprises" WHERE "entreprises"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "b50b7beb-7417-4110-b602-660e9ecf067e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Entreprise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entreprises".* FROM "entreprises" WHERE "entreprises"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "b50b7beb-7417-4110-b602-660e9ecf067e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

is there a setup in my code creating this please ?

Comment: Your first web app in Ruby is making SQL calls on startup? Did you copy a bunch of code from some online tutorial? You're not going to get very far copying and running code bases you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems like N+1 Query problem :)

I think you have this code in your controller;

```
@entrepies = Entrepry.all
```

And call in the view like this;

```
<% @enrepies.each do |entrepry| %>
    <p><%= entrepry.title %></p>
    <p>
        <% entrepry.users.each do |user| %>
            <%= user.name %><br/>
        <% end %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This code have n+1 query problem(Every entrepry object call user object from database because user does not include the entrepries query). You must be join or include the user table on your entreprises query. Just like this; `Entrepry.all.includes(:user)`